# C# Error - Not all code path return value

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error "not all code paths return a value" in method `getdatatoTextbox`.

Please help me fix this problem.

```
private DataTable getdatatoTextbox(int RegistrationId)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DotNetFunda;User id=sa;Password=sqluser");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Getdatatotextbox", con);
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RegistrationId;
        DataTable dtdatanew = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        da.Fill(dtdatanew);
        con.Close();
        return dtdatanew;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: return null or throw exception

Comment: Your catch{} returns nothing

Comment: Look at all the paths in your code. Do all of them return a value or else throw an exception? What happens if you hit the catch block? What do you want to happen? What would the person calling this method want to happen?

Comment: also get rid of the code in the finally section, refactor your Sql Objects and wrap them around a `using() { }` to take advantage of `Auto Disposing` and your error states that it expects a return type so either declare the datatable outside the try also learn to google the error message if worst comes to worst..

Comment: you need to put a return value in your catch block

Answer (score 9):

If the event of an Exception nothing is being returned which is not valid if you have a non `void` return type in your method. Also never swallow exceptions, its bad practice and when something goes wrong you come back later asking questions on SO with why.

On another note, you should wrap all your Disposables in `using` blocks. If your query fails your Db connection will remain open the way your code is now, I know you have the dispose in the finally but that wont even compile because you defined it inside your `try` block.

This would fix the problem and give you an Exception (a good thing) when something unexpected happens. You can handle it outside the method or let it bubble up to the original caller and then do something.

```
private DataTable getdatatoTextbox(int RegistrationId)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DotNetFunda;User id=sa;Password=sqluser"))
    using(SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Getdatatotextbox", con))
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd))
    {
        con.Open();
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RegistrationId;
        DataTable dtdatanew = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtdatanew);
        return dtdatanew;
    }
}
```